# error while compiling ow2 frascati

Tags: java, maven, signing

I am facing the following error while compiling the ow2 frascati software with the maven clean insatll command

> class "org.eclipse.core.runtime.QualifiedName"'s signer information
>   does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

The frascati continuous intregation server is also facing the same problem. 
http://bamboo.ow2.org/browse/SCA-DEF-JOB1-1919/

What should i Io?